# Distribution of value with multithreaded self-increment.

Tags: probability

This originates from a computer science problem: suppose you have a variable $i$ with init value $0$. Then you create $n$ threads that each thread $i\rightarrow i+1$ for $m$ times. What's the possible value of $i$ when every thread finish.

One would expected that $i=mn$, but the tricky part is, there is a phenomena called "data racing". In short, $i\rightarrow i+1$ are not "atomic". It consists of 3 events:

1. Read from memory (to registers, you can suppose each thread owns a private variable called "register")
2. Add 1
3. Write to memory

We could give a time order of $2mn$ events (we ignore the add 1 event because its time ordering is irrelevant). Here is an example that $i\not =mn$, Consider two thread $A,B$ and each thread do $i\rightarrow i+1$ only once. Here's a time order:

1. $A$ read
2. $B$ read
3. $B$ write (now $i=1$)
4. $A$ write (now $i=1$)

Now $i=1$, not $2$. A surprising fact is: the minimal possible value of $i$ is 2 when $m,n\le 2$, no matter how big $m,n$ is.

> $A$ read, other thread run all loop, $B$ run $m-1$ loop, $A$ write($i=1$), $B$ read, $A$ run $m-1$ loop, $B$ write.

So we can consider the probability version: suppose you have a random partition of $\{1,\dots,2mn\}$ into $n$ sets of size $2m$. And each set is assigned to a thread, denote note the read step in thread $j$ loop $k$ by $R_{jk}$ and write step by $W_{jk}$. This induce a bijection $\{R_{jk},W_{jk}:j=0,\dots,n,\,k=0,\dots,m\}$ and $\{1,\dots,2mn\}$ such that order of $\{R_{jk},W_{jk}\}$ is preserved for fixed $j$.

Now the final value of $i$ can be decided ad follows: the last event must be write, traceback to last read event of same thread, then trace back to last write event (of any thread). Then stop when there's only read event in front. Final value of $i$ is the number of read (equal to number of write) in the traceback. So my question is what's the expectation/probability distribution of final value of $i$?